# Problem using pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay to find Dates from DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas Series (with Index being dates) and I am trying to extract dates at a regular interval (365 days) form this Series. In order to make it simple, I am using `CustomBusinessDay`. This seemed to work fine but for one particular example it failed meaning i probably did not understand exactly how it works.

This is what I am doing :

I have a Series "Test" :

```py
test
Out[29]: 
2008-04-02    0.006084
2008-04-03   -0.002923
2008-04-04    0.002602
```

etc..

more specifically here is where the problem arise :

```py
test[512:516]
Out[31]: 
2010-03-30   -0.002650
2010-03-31   -0.002898
2010-04-01    0.016151
2010-04-06    0.003690
dtype: float64
```

I created a Custom Business Day using the original index and create a date range with a frequency of 365D and add `0*CustCal` in order to get dates that are part of the original index :

```py
CustCal=pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=test.index)
tempRestrikeDates = pd.date_range(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1], freq='365D')+0*CustCal
```

However, as you can see on the results below, '2010-04-02' is part of `tempRestrikeDates` but is not in the original index of test.

```py
tempRestrikeDates
Out[35]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2008-04-02', '2009-04-02', '2010-04-02', '2011-04-04',
               '2012-04-02', '2013-04-01', '2014-04-01', '2015-04-01',
               '2016-03-31', '2017-03-31', '2018-04-02', '2019-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Is there something i got wrong in the way to use `CustomBusinessDay` and adding `0*CustCal` in order to get a date that is part of `CustCal`?

Is there another efficient way to achieve this ?

The results should be :

```py
tempRestrikeDates
Out[35]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2008-04-02', '2009-04-02', '2010-04-01', '2011-04-04',
               '2012-04-02', '2013-04-01', '2014-04-01', '2015-04-01',
               '2016-03-31', '2017-03-31', '2018-04-02', '2019-04-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Before reading through it I have a noob question. Doesn't `0*CustCal` always return zero?

Comment: @Gio : no, I am not sure exactly what is the logic but it is supposed, as I understand, to add such as to get a date belonging to CustCal. If you look at this results done without the "0*CustCal", the date in 2018 has been modified. 
tempRestrikeDates
Out[39]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2008-04-02', '2009-04-02', '2010-04-02', '2011-04-02',
               '2012-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2014-04-01', '2015-04-01',
               '2016-03-31', '2017-03-31', '2018-03-31', '2019-03-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='365D')